# Disabling pointers in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers

How can I get the value of a variable into another variable without them having the same pointer? That is, in the code below, my `keepScale` value is getting updated to `1` when after `recognizer.rotation` is set to `1`.

**Code**

```
var keepScale : CGFloat = 1

func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
                recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
            
            keepScale = recognizer.scale
            println(keepScale)

            recognizer.scale = 1
            println(keepScale)
            
        }
    }
```

**Example Logs**

> 0.5
>
> 1.0

Comment: Is this your exact code? The behavior you're describing is not what you should be seeing. CGFloat is a struct and has copy semantics.

Comment: Yep exact code. I thought it was strange too, I've never had to deal with pointers in Swift. Maybe the issue is unrelated to this code, I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so actually since a scale is a ratio I had to multiply my `keepScale` value by `recognizer.scale` and not simply set it to equal.